# How can you make a microphone toggle with unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, microphone

I had a question regarding microphone toggles. I've been searching online for a solid way to make a mic toggle, and couldn't find it. Just wanted to ask if something like this would do the job:

```
string _deviceName = Microphone.devices[0];

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.M) {
micIsOn = !micIsOn;
}

if (micIsOn) {
Microphone.End(_deviceName);
}

else {
Microphone.Start(_deviceName, true, 10, AudioSettings.outputSampleRate;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If his is being called in update, which I think it is, you should put the rest of the if statements in the first one. This way, it will update when you press the button and not every frame. You are currently keep starting a new microphon every frame.

```
string _deviceName = Microphone.devices[0];

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.M) {
    micIsOn = !micIsOn;
    if (micIsOn) {
        Microphone.End(_deviceName);
    }

    else {
    Microphone.Start(_deviceName, true, 10, AudioSettings.outputSampleRate);
     //also you need the ")"
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like it didn't work?

Comment: As in it isn't actually turning on and off the microphone. Anything else I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Put a print statement in the micIsOn if statement and in the else function. This way you can check if they are being called. If they are being called, it may be a problem with your microphone or your devicename is wrong. Is micIsOn changing?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the very late response.

Comment: Yes, micIsOn is changing whenever you click M.

Comment: @PratyushMahadevaiah That must mean that your microphone is not working, Microphone.Start doesn’t work, or something like that because it is being called. I would consider trying different ways of turning on microphone and receiving mic input, because that method might not work

Comment: Hey, thanks. Do you know any ways to get the first available microphone, and enable and disable it? Thanks a lot

Comment: @PratyushMahadevaiah Sorry I don’t know anything about microphones, but here is what I found on Unity https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.Start.html basically l, you need to create an audio clip variable and set it to Microphone.Start. Does that make sense?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much, Walter. I greatly appreciate it :)